# AWS CLI to Check Free Tier Usage Limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Is there a way to check my AWS root account Free Tier usage via CLI?

I do not have access to AWS Console (i.e no root password), but I do have the root access key. Therefore, while I cannot use the (browser) billing dashboard approach, I believe I should have full CLI access to check all data.

I tried to search the [CLI documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/index.html#cli-aws), but to no avail.

I hope to retrieve similar data as to the **Top Free Tier Service by Usage** from the AWS Billing Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `get-cost-and-usage` command to retrieve Free Tier usage information.

example:

```bash
aws ce get-cost-and-usage --time-period Start=2023-01-01,End=2023-01-31 --granularity MONTHLY --metrics "BlendedCost" --group-by Type=DIMENSION,Key=SERVICE Type=TAG,Key=USAGE_TYPE
```

You can adjust the `--time-period` parameter to query for different months or time ranges.

P.s The BlendedCost metric includes information about the cost, and you can check if you have exceeded your Free Tier limits or not.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example!


I managed to get the output to resemble the free tier interface using the following:
`aws ce get-cost-and-usage --time-period Start=2023-09-01,End=2023-11-01 --granularity MONTHLY --metrics "BLENDED_COST" "USAGE_QUANTITY" "NORMALIZED_USAGE_AMOUNT" --group-by Type=DIMENSION,Key=SERVICE Type=DIMENSION,Key=USAGE_TYPE --output table`


I found it useful to read the [AWS Data Dictionary](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cur/latest/userguide/Lineitem-columns.html) to understand what each metrics mean too!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cost Explorer API to achieve this:

```
aws ce get-cost-and-usage ...
```

You'll need to use `Expression` and supply the necessary parameters to return free tier usage params.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_Expression.html